403 Error on Login for Multiple Subdomains Except One - AWS EC2 and CloudFront
I'm encountering an issue where only one of my subdomains are functioning normally. All the other subdomains, hosted on AWS EC2 and served via CloudFront, lead to a 403 error page upon attempting to log in. This occurs after submitting credentials, and the issue is consistent across all user accounts.
I believe I've eliminated the possibility of it be a .htacess corrupted and any issues relating to ip address.
thanks in advance
confirmed that I can log in with only one subdomain,
confirmed inbound and outbound were configured properly.
